# jQuery smooth scroll somehow breaking bootstrap navbar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using some jQuery code to do a smooth animated page scroll using a button but this one line of code is breaking my bootstrap nav bar such that it isn't collapsing when I click collapse and is collapsing when I click on an embedded dropdown-toggle button. Using bootstrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js with this navbar:

```
<div class="navbar-wrapper appnavbar navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top" id="mainNav"> 
      <div class="container-fullwidth">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="active" [routerLink]="['/']" class="navbar-left pull-left"><img class="img-responsive" src="assets/img/pup1.png" style="position: relative; left:2px; max-width:auto; height:50px; margin-left:-7px;"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>-->
                <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/']" class="active" routerLinkActive="active">#pup</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a [routerLink]="['/howitworks']" class="active" routerLinkActive="active">how it works </a></li> <!-- about -->
                <li class="active dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">events <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a [routerLink]="['/']" class="active" routerLinkActive="active">Featured</a></li>
```

All of this jQuery is required to make the smooth scroll button work and this first line is the jQuery line that breaks my navbar:

```
function collapseNavbar(){$(".navbar").offset().top>50?$(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse"):$(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse")}
```

This is the rest of the jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(collapseNavbar),$(document).ready(collapseNavbar),

$(function(){$("a.page-scroll").bind("click",function(e){var t=$(this);$("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:$(t.attr("href")).offset().top},1500,"easeInOutExpo"),e.preventDefault()})}),

$(".navbar-collapse ul li a").click(function(){$(this).closest(".collapse").collapse("toggle")});
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you create codepen for same?

Comment: Do you have a link with the code in use? I've had a similar problem with smooth scrolling and Bootstrap components.

Answer (score 0):

Any luck with the following?  My guess is the scroll-to is intercepting that dropdown click, or it is working, but due to the fixed navbar it is positioned at the point of injection, which is likely up beyond the viewport.

```js
$(function(){$("a.page-scroll:not(.dropdown-toggle)").bind("click",function(e){var t=$(this);$("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop:$(t.attr("href")).offset().top},1500,"easeInOutExpo"),e.preventDefault()})}),
```